# Включение умной лампочки Яндекса через API

Tags: http-status-code-404, iot, умный-дом

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: отправляю запрос на включение умной лампочки по адресу `https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/devices/action`, получаю ответ:

> 404 Page Not Found.

Пытался изменить адрес на `https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/devices/action/af8cd79f-c021-41bb-8d85...` (добавил ID лампочки), результат такой же.

Comment: как вы отправляете запрос? подробнее расскажите. Используете какой-нибудь ЯП или постман.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, curl -i -X POST 'https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/devices/action' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer 123qwe456a...' \
-H 'X-Request-Id: ff36a3cc-ec...' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{body_goes_here}'

Comment: Что передаете в теле запроса `{body_goes_here}`?

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода для изменения состояния лампы:вкл/выкл
`def TurnOnOffLamp(token: str, device_id: str, turn: bool): url = r'https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/devices/actions' headers = {'Authorization': token} data = {'devices': [{'id': device_id, 'actions': [{'type':  'devices.capabilities.on_off', 'state': {'instance':  'on', 'value': turn}}]}]} return requests.post(url=url, headers=headers , data=json.dumps(data)).content`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в url. Правильный урл - https://api.iot.yandex.net/v1.0/user/devices/actions

Вся информация об АПИ и методах находится на официальном сайте
https://yandex.ru/dev/dialogs/smart-home/doc/concepts/platform-protocol.html